# Mongoose array of objects expects boolean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

In my code, I have the following model.

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema ( {
    title: String,
    owner: String,
    creationDate: Date,
    editionDate: Date,
    tags: [String],
    score: Number,
    votes:
    [
        {
            user: String,
            type: Boolean
        }
    ],
    text: String
} );
```

And I have the following method in the post controller.

```
async store (request, response)
{
    const {title = "", owner = "", tags = [], text = ""} = request.body;
    var creationDate = new Date ();
    var offset = creationDate.getTimezoneOffset ();
    var minutes = creationDate.getMinutes ();
    creationDate.setMinutes (minutes-offset);
    const newPost = await Post.create ({title, owner, creationDate, editionDate: null, tags, score: 0, votes: [], text});
    return response.json (newPost);
}
```

If I try to use `votes: [{user: "", type: true}]` instead of `votes: []`, I get the following error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Post validation failed: votes.0: Cast to Boolean failed for value "{ user: '', type: true }" at path "votes", votes: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { user: '', type: true } ]" at path "votes"
```

If I use `votes: [true]`, no error occurs and the created object has a votes array with `true` inside.

The same error occurs if I try to push `{user: "", type: true}` into the array with an update method.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you tried to set default value to the votes, so then the value will be false or true by default if the user didn't insert a value.

```js
Votes: [
    {
        user: String,
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
]
```

Comment: If I use `default: {user: "", type: true}`, the created object has a `true` in its votes array.